# Deleting old records from a very big table based on criteria

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sql-loader

I have a table (Table A) that contains 300 million records, I want to do a data retention activity on basis of some criteria. So I want to delete about 200M records of the table.

Concerning the performance, I planned to create a new table (Table-B) with the oldest 10M records from Table-A. Then I can select records from Table-B which matches the criteria and will delete it in Table A.

Extracting 10M records from Table-A and loading into Table-B using SQL Loader takes  ~5 hours.

I already created indexes and I use parallel 32 wherever applicable.

What I wanted to know is,

- Is there any better way to extract from Table-A and to load it in Table-B.
- Is there any better approach other than creating a temp table(Table-B).

DBMS: Oracle 10g, PL/SQL and Shell.

Thanks.

Comment: Are both tables in same database? If yes, whey are you using SQL Loader to load? Can't you simply `insert into tableB select * from tableA`?  Also create tableB as `no logging` for faster inserts. Google `nologging` for more details on this.

Comment: I agree with @Utsav, just `insert /*+ append */ into t2 select * from t1 where whatever` should take minutes not hours. It's the `delete` I would be more worried about. Do you have the option of partitioning for next time you need to do this?

Comment: Also regarding "Is there any better approach other than creating a temp table(Table-B)", I don't understand your process logic. What is Table-B for? I mean, an alternative to creating it would be not creating it.

Comment: as others already stated: why do you need this table B? How long does it take if you use insert append? On which table have you created indexes? What do you want to achieve with your operations?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson , I am having some criteria based on that criteria i will delete records from the Table A.
As I mentioned in Table-A 300M records are there if i applied that criteria on Table-A and trying to delete all the required records  at once then it will take a lot time  in selecting them and then deleting them .
so I am trying to delete them in batches. I will take first batch of 10M records and then insert this batch into Table-B and on Table-B i will apply my criteria and select the records that need to be delete and  then i will delete them from Table A.

Comment: I'm afraid there aren't enough details in your question for anyone to provide a solution.

Comment: how many records do you have to delete altogether?

Comment: @miracle173, ~200 Million might come under  deletion criteria

Comment: so you want to delete about 2/3 of the records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete 70% of the records of your table, the best way is to create a new table that contains the remaining 30% of the rows, drop the old table and rename the new table to the name of the old table. One possibility to create the new table is a create-table-as-select statement (CTAS), but there are also possibilities that make the impact on the running system much smaller, e.g. one can use materialized views to select the remaining data and convert the materialized vie to a table. The details of the approach depend on the requirements.
This reading and writing is much more efficient then deleting the rows of the old table.

If you delete the rows of the old table it is probably necessary to reorganize the old table which will also end up in writing these remaining 30% of data.

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning the table by your criteria may be an option.

Consider a case with the criteria is the month.  All January data falls into the Jan partition.  All February data falls into the Feb partition...

Then when it comes time to drop all the old January data, you just drop the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Using rowid best to use but inline cursor can help u more
Insert into table a values ( select * from table B where = criteria) then truncate table A

Answer (score 0):

- Is there any better way to extract from Table-A and to load it in? You can use parallel CTAS - create table-b as select from table-a. You can use compression and parallel query in one step.
- Table-B. Is there any better approach other than creating a temp
  table(Table-B)? Better approach would be partitioning of table a

Answer (score -1):

Probably better approach would be partitioning of Table A but if not you can try fast and simple:

```
declare
    i pls_integer :=0 ;
begin
    for r in
    (   -- select what you want to move to second table
        SELECT  
            rowid as rid,
            col1,
            col2,
            col3
        FROM
            table_a t
        WHERE
            t.col < SYSDATE - 30 --- or other criteria 
    )
    loop
        insert /*+ append */ into table_b values (r.col1, r.col2, r.col3 ); -- insert it to second table
        delete from table_a where rowid = r.rid; -- and delete it
        if i < 500 -- check your best commit interval
        then
            i:=i+1;
        else
            commit;
            i:=0;
        end if;    
    end loop;
    commit;
end;
```

In above example you will move your records in small 500 rows  transactions. You can optimize it using collection and bulk insert but i wanted to keep simple code.

Comment: -1 That is not a good advice. That will blow up the duration of the load from 5 hours to many more hours. As others already stated: Fist think about if it is really necessary to use a table B, second if it is necessary then use 'insert append' and maybe nologging. your method takes none of this into account but increases the time to delete the data. The append-hint has no effect on an insert-values statement and constantly switching between pl/sql and sql context will make this approach even more slow.

Comment: Plus it's `/*+ append_values */` for an `insert ... values` statement, and that was only added in 11.2 and the OP is still on 10g. And there seems to be a `commit` in that loop.

Answer (score -1):

I was missing one index on a column that i was using  in a search criteria.
Apart from this there was some indexes missing on referenced tables too.

> Apart from this @miracle173 answer is also good but we are having some foreign key too that might create problem if we had used that approach.

+1 to @miracle173